# In Weaviate, what is the recommended way to handle paginated results to avoid duplicates?

Tags: weaviate

As per Weaviate [documentation](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/graphql/additional-operators#performance-and-resource-considerations--limitations):

> The pagination setup is not stateful. If the database state has
> changed between retrieving two pages there is no guarantee that your
> pages cover all results.

I am having an issue right now where, when someone publishes their new **Player X** then another **Player Y** ranking could go either higher or lower from the search relevance.

If **Player Y** (`ranked 89` before the update) has already appeared in **page 81-90** (currently loaded) and after an update this player could go to `ranked 92` thus, this player will be part of **page 91-100** which will appear like a duplicate record for the user viewing the page. It is more noticeable on our side since we are using infinite scroll (business rule).

Is there like a recommended way on how to handle this on the application side? Any suggestions to move forward?